# Get 2nd value in loop

Tags: python, loops, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Currently writing a telegram bot to fetch live data from a Envrio+ phat on a Raspberry Pi...

When you run the built in example it will always print the below:

```
The current tempurature is 21.70818430223153 *C 

The current pressure is  700.2708792437015hPa

The Current Humidty is 84.54408663293306 %
```

On the next print of the while loop it will give you the correct data of the environment. To get around this I need to only fetch the 2nd set of data not the first.

I've tried indenting the variables in a while loop but that does not work through the bot and hit a brick wall.

Below is what works in the bot but fetches the same values back as posted above, every time the weather states are fetched.

```
def weather(bot, update):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    temp = bme280.get_temperature()
    pressure = bme280.get_pressure()
    humidity = bme280.get_humidity()
    current_temp = "The current tempurature is " + str(temp)  + " *C " + "\nThe current pressure is  " +  str(pressure) + "hPa" + "\nThe Current Humidty is " + str(humidity) + " %"
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=current_temp)
```

The while loop stills brings the same values, not the next value in the example loop.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work through this over the last few days, it took a little longer as im still learning python as I go but before is the working code:

```
while True: 
    if counter < 2:
        temperature = bme280.get_temperature()
        pressure = bme280.get_pressure()
        humidity = bme280.get_humidity()
        counter = counter + 1
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("""Temperature: {:05.2f} *C
    Pressure: {:05.2f} hPa
    Relative humidity: {:05.2f} %
    """.format(temperature, pressure, humidity))
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the first request or the first loop initialises the bot and give back default values, thereafter you get real values.

Maybe one of these two strategies might work:

```
1.) Send a single request first and ignore the result, thereafter do a while loop
2.) Initialise a counter before the while loop and if counter = 1 then ignore results and loop
```

Some more code might help narrow down answers.